# How do I prevent form submission if the form is invalid?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

So when the form is invalid and I click submit, it just redirects to /home because of `return redirect('/')`. So what do I have to `return` here to prevent form submission and raise an error message? Here's my code:

**views.py**

```
class BoxesView(ListView, FormMixin):
    template_name = 'polls.html'  # extends base.html
    form_class = UserRegistrationForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BoxesView, self).get_context_data()

        question_list = Question.objects.all().order_by('-date')
        choice = Choice.objects.all()
        context['question_list'] = question_list
        context['choice'] = choice

        q_list = []
        returned_list = []

        for i in question_list:
            q_list.append(i)

        for a, b in CATEGORY_CHOICES:
            name = resolve(self.request.path_info).url_name
            if b == name:
                category = a

        search = self.request.GET.get('search')
        posts = Post.objects.all().filter(category=category).order_by('-date')
        if search:
            posts = posts.filter(
                Q(title__icontains=search) |
                Q(content__icontains=search)
            )
        else:
            posts = Post.objects.all().filter(category=category).order_by('-date')

        context['posts'] = posts

        total = 0
        for post in posts:
            returned_list.append(post)
            total += 1
            if total == 4:
                total = 0
                for i in q_list:
                    returned_list.append(i)
                    q_list.remove(i)
                    break

        paginator = Paginator(returned_list, 14)
        page = self.request.GET.get('page')

        try:
            lst = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
            lst = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
            lst = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

        context['lst'] = lst

        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        pass

def register(request):
    form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password, email=email)
        user.save()
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        print(form.errors)
        form = UserRegistrationForm()
    return redirect('/')
```

And in my `forms.py` it raises an exception error to the terminal but the form still submits.

**forms.py**

```
class UserRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=25)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    confirm_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User

        fields = [
            'username',
            'email',
            'password',
        ]

    def clean(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')

        current_emails = User.objects.filter(email=email)

        if current_emails.exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("That email is taken")
```

**base.html**

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url 'register' %}">{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="registerBox">
        <p><label for="id_username"></label> <input id="id_username" type="text" name="username" maxlength="30" placeholder="username"/></p>
        <p><label for="id_email"></label> <input type="email" name="email" id="id_email" placeholder="email"/></p>
    <p><label for="id_password"></label> <input type="password" name="password" id="id_password" placeholder="password"/></p>
        <p><label for="id_confirm_password"></label> <input type="password" name="confirm_password" id="id_confirm_password" placeholder="confirm password"/></p>
    <input type="submit" value="register" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Any idea?

Comment: is it correct indent in the last line `return redirect('/')` in `views.py`?

Comment: I've tried both and they have the same result.

Comment: `def register(request)` it is the POST method, can you show the view that render this form(GET)?

Comment: I've added it now in the edit.

Comment: I'm confused. It looks like nobody answered the actual question! How to prevent submission if the form is invalid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be trying to prevent *submission* when the form is invalid. What you should be doing is accepting the submission, checking the errors, then returning the errors and the filled-in form to the template.

But you are doing three things that prevent that: you are always re-instantiating the form when it is invalid, you always redirect, and you don't show errors or previous values in the template.

So you should do this:

```
def register(request):
    form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password, email=email)
        user.save()
        return redirect('/')
    return render('mytemplate.html', {"form": form})
```

and in the template:

```
<div class="registerBox">
    {{ form.non_field_errors }}
    <p>{{ form.username.label_tag }} {{ form.username }} {{ form.username.errors }}</p>
    <p>{{ form.email.label_tag }} {{ form.email }} {{ form.email.errors }}</p>
    <p><label for="id_password"></label> <input type="password" name="password" id="id_password" placeholder="password"/></p>
    <p><label for="id_confirm_password"></label> <input type="password" name="confirm_password" id="id_confirm_password" placeholder="confirm password"/></p>
    <input type="submit" value="register" />
</div>
```

Comment: Yes you're right and using the form context is much better than using input tags, so this fixes the problem. Just one question - even when I exclude `{{ form.errors }}` and `{{ form.non_field_errors }}` in the template, it still shows the errors (e.g. "Please fill out this field", "Please include an '@' in email" etc). Is this normal or is `{{ form.errors }}` and `{{ form.non_field_errors }}` supposed to render something else?

Comment: That's nothing to do with Django, it's the browser trying to be clever thanks to HTML5 form validation. You can disable it in the form element with `<form novalidate method=...>`.

Comment: Right, was confused because it wasn't there when I was using the input elements instead of `{{ form }}`. But as I said before, the `{{ form.errors }}` and `{{ form.non_field_errors }}` are not doing anything? Whether I include them or not nothing changes. Any idea why?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean; the errors will be populated once the form has been submitted and the page re-rendered by Django. If the HTML5 validation is preventing the form being submitted in the first place, you won't see any errors from Django.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
if form.is_valid():
    ...
else:
    return form_invalid(form)
```

Comment: I've solved the question, but do you know how i would use `form_invalid(form)`? I tried your code but got "form_invalid" is not defined.

Comment: nice, you already solved it. what I'm saying is you need to return the invalid form, anyway  this is my form_invalid,my mistake for not showing it to you, because i just wrote the syntax on my mind.

Comment: def form_invalid(self, form):
        messages.error(self.request, _(u'Please select at least one field.'))
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))

Comment: I don't think that would have worked with mine because I needed `request` as a parameter, and when I put `self` in `request` didn't work. Anyway thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You should use ajax validation if you do not want to submit invalid form.

Comment: Shouldn't it automatically prevent submission if a field is hasn't been completed (e.g. username or password)? Thought this was built in. I will look at ajax though.

Comment: No, form is submitted anyway. You must use javascript validation to prevent submit of invalid form.